# WSO2 DSS : Setup data service using Oracle stored procedure/function that has an array of string/varchar2 as input parameter

Tags: arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, wso2-data-services-server, input-parameters

I'm a database developer and we're using WSO2 Data Service Server to build web services based on Oracle stored procedure calls. One of the stored procedures takes an array as an input parameter.
Unfortunately DSS is unable to map array this input parameter. Tried going through the WSO2 documentation but it didn't. 
I tried playing with the parameter definition to make is Scalar or Array as shown below.

Can some one please help in what configuration changes needs to be done?

Also can you please indicate how will the URL look like for a RESTful service that will take array of data as input parameters ?

Below is the sample Oracle stored procedure code and the corresponding WSO2 DSS configuration script. The database grants and permission are not an issue.

```
/* PL/SQL Code Start */

create or replace type str_array as table of varchar2(100) ;

create or replace procedure procarray (
    pv_arr IN str_array,
    pv_rset OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    open pv_rset for select column_value as str from table(pv_arr);
End;

show errors;  

/* PL/SQL Code End */
```

The webservice configuration is as follows

```
<data name="test_arrayCall">
   <config id="CDE_ODS_DIT">
      <property name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@zzzz:1521</property>
      <property name="username">xxxxxxx</property> 
      <property name="password">yyyyyyy</property>
   </config>
   <query id="callarray" useConfig="CDE_ODS_DIT">
      <sql>call xxxxxxx.procarray(?,?);</sql>
      <result element="rows" rowName="row">
         <element column="STR" name="STR" namespace="STR" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="pv_arr" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING"/> <!-- When making a call the service response throws an Oracle Error -->

      <!-- Below parameter setting doesn't work and the service fails to get itself registered successfully --> 
      <!-- <param name="pv_arr" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="ARRAY" structType="xxxxxxx.STR_ARRAY"/> /> -->

      <param name="pv_rset" sqlType="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" type="OUT"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="getdata">
      <call-query href="callarray">
         <with-param name="pv_arr" query-param="pv_arr"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

Below is the sample request and response output when passing two values to the stored procedure
Request :

```
<body>
   <p:getdata xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--1 or more occurrences-->
      <xs:pv_arr xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">A</xs:pv_arr>
      <xs:pv_arr xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">B</xs:pv_arr>
   </p:getdata>
</body>
```

Response :

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:axis2ns14="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Value>axis2ns14:DATABASE_ERROR</soapenv:Value>
   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: test_arrayCall
Location: \test_arrayCall.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: getdata
Current Params: {pv_arr={A,B}}
Nested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character


</soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail>
      <axis2ns13:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns13="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <axis2ns13:current_params>{pv_arr={A,B}}</axis2ns13:current_params>
         <axis2ns13:current_request_name>getdata</axis2ns13:current_request_name>
         <axis2ns13:nested_exception>java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character</axis2ns13:nested_exception>
         <axis2ns13:source_data_service>
            <axis2ns13:location>\test_arrayCall.dbs</axis2ns13:location>
            <axis2ns13:default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice</axis2ns13:default_namespace>
            <axis2ns13:description>N/A</axis2ns13:description>
            <axis2ns13:data_service_name>test_arrayCall</axis2ns13:data_service_name>
         </axis2ns13:source_data_service>
         <axis2ns13:ds_code>DATABASE_ERROR</axis2ns13:ds_code>
      </axis2ns13:DataServiceFault>
   </soapenv:Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the sql query as

```
   <query id="callarray" useConfig="CDE_ODS_DIT">
      <sql>call xxxxxxx.procarray(?,str_array(?));</sql>
      <result element="rows" rowName="row">
         <element column="STR" name="STR" namespace="STR" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="pv_arr" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING"/> <!-- When making a call the service response throws an Oracle Error -->

      <!-- Below parameter setting doesn't work and the service fails to get itself registered successfully --> 
      <!-- <param name="pv_arr" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="ARRAY" structType="xxxxxxx.STR_ARRAY"/> /> -->

      <param name="pv_rset" sqlType="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" type="OUT"/>
   </query>
```

Please note that the array data should be passed as the type str_array in the query as in the bove sample